# multithreaded database operation in php

Tags: php, multithreading

I have one table called domains. it has 200 millions rows. i want to validate those domain names. following is my code. but i want to run 1000 threads, so that i can validate 1000 domains in one thread, as i have 200 millions rows in my table.

```
for ($i=0; $i<=1000; $i++){
   check_domains();
}

function check_domains(){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM urls where status=0 limit 1";
    $result = mysql_query ($sql);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array ($result);
    //some validation and pinging the domain.
    if ($validated){
         $sql = "update urls set status=1 where id=".$row['id'];
         $result = mysql_query ($sql);
    }
}
```

can anyone please suggest some solution to make it multi threaded in php.

Comment: I'd recommend pthreads: http://php.net/manual/de/book.pthreads.php . Furthermore, please use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead of `mysql`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pcntl_fork` inside your script to duplicate the thread and process 1000 entries per child thread.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php